# Why does Custom UITableViewCell *sometimes* cause an NSInvalidArgumentException?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell`, but when I dequeue the cell, *sometimes* it throws an `NSInvalidArgumentException`:

> [UITableViewCell nameLabel]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x3b4e7f0
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[UITableViewCell nameLabel]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x3b4e7f0'

Now, my custom `UITableViewCell` does have an attribute `nameLabel`, so I am confused why it is throwing this error.  Below is the code I use to dequeue the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    CTMenuItemVO* key = [[[self retrieveCartItems] allKeys] objectAtIndex:row]; 
    NSNumber* quantity = [[self retrieveCartItems] objectForKey:key];
    static NSString* SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier2";
    OrderItemCell* cell = (OrderItemCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                            SectionsTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) { 
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrderItemCell"    
                                                                     owner:nil
                                                                   options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (OrderItemCell*) currentObject;
                break;
            }               
        }
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = key.Name;
    cell.qtyLabel.text = [quantity stringValue];

    return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Changing the `isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]` check to an `OrderItemCell` produces another error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

I guess this occurs because it leaves the `for` loop without assigning the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were two *different* copies named `OrderItemCell`.  Not sure how the doppelganger got into my folder structure (even though there was only one referenced in my workspace), but once I removed the impostor, it worked like a charm every time.

Answer (score 1):

Are all the objects in `topLevelObjects` of type `OrderItemCell`? There is a possibility that you are assigning a different object to `cell`, typecasting it to a different object and therefore the unrecognized selector error.

Comment: Sorry, no.  Instead of throwing the previously stated Exception, I get another: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, assuming that it leaves the 'for' loop without finding any cells of that particular kind.

Answer (score 0):

Change [UITableViewCell class] to [OrderItemCell class].